# UI Orientation Change-Make it independent for rotation

Tags: android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android

I have a one condition. There is a SDK in my Project.who change activity orientation when it requires the performing an operation. But after its operation i have to set activity orientation according to the device orientation.

I used following method to set screen orientation back to previous orientation. But when i set it. Next time if i rotate my device  my activity is not changing orientation according to the device.

Can anyone suggest me the proper solution to make my activity flexible again. Or solving this situation. Thanks In advance.

```
if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation !=Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)

  {
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When device rotates the your activity will take take it's orientation according to the device but if set it's orientation then it will not change with device orientation.

refer this blog:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Comment: i know . But how can i resize my activity orientation when external SDK change its rotation.

Comment: when orientation changes your layout-land folder is being looked for views in landscape mode else your default folder. You can use it for resizing..

Comment: i made it land folder. but my dear there is need to rotate Activity rotation at run time when sdk internally change my ui rotation. I understand what u said. I have to refresh my screen  rotation.

Comment: when rotation takes place activity destroys and starts again so you don't need to refresh it but you need to set it's view and data as per your need......